# Using spaCy Specific Type Annotations (Python 3.11)

Tags: nlp, annotations, spacy, python-3.11

I want to indicate that certain parameters are of spaCy return objects. For example, `corpus` is an item returned as a result of calling `nlp`. Assume that `hh` is located in different modules.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def hh(corpus):
    pass

result = hh(nlp(text))
```

How to annotate parameters with spaCy built-in object, for instince like `corpus:spacy_token`?

I had a hard time figuring this out. Try this and that but no result. The property like `lemma_` is not detected in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import the spacy objects and use them like regular type annotations

```py
from spacy.tokens import Token
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def hh(corpus: Token):
    pass

result = hh(nlp(text))
```

Comment: I've tried this. But it doesn't do anything. I hope that VS Code would recognize the property, like `lemma_` in `token.lemma_` should be orange (in my syntax highlighting), but this is plain white instead. Meaning the property isn't recognized.